# Need a few >2k people to help with the merge of the Recovery tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

I would like to merge [recovery](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/recovery) into [data-recovery](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/data-recovery).
A good ~90% (at a glance) of the ~500 questions tagged [recovery](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/recovery) are about [data-recovery](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/data-recovery).
The other ~10% are about things like [password-recovery](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/password-recovery) or [recovery-mode](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/recovery-mode).

Obviously if you think this is a silly idea, make it known quickly, but failing that, I would appreciate some help scanning through the current [recovery](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/recovery) questions to make sure questions that *aren't* about [data-recovery](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/data-recovery) have appropriate tags before the merge.

I don't expect (or want) anybody to go through 500 questions but there is a lot of low-hanging fruit that the search function makes easy to identify. You still need to check (because not all of these will apply).

- [51 questions that have "password" in them](https://askubuntu.com/search?q=[recovery]%20is%3Aq%20password). Probably need the password-recovery tag instead.
- [73 questions that have "recovery" and "mode" in them](https://askubuntu.com/search?q=[recovery]%20is%3Aq%20recovery%20mode). Probably a mis-tag.

There are probably other searches that identify good candidates. Add them to the list.

And again, unless it desperately needs other editing, **if it's about data recovery, just leave it**.
The tag merge will deal with these without bumping them up to the front page.

---

[First question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/430753/i-want-to-reinstall-my-ubuntu-and-i-want-to-delete-my-partitions-but-i-dont-kn) I looked at from the second list was about recovery partitions (eg bootable install media that OEMs stick on their disks). I'm not sure how we tag those.

Comment: How do we tag [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/235890/how-can-i-access-data-on-a-computer-without-knowing-the-login-password) - guy wants to recover files, but disk isn't damaged etc. Password recovery is secondary (maybe not even needed).

Comment: @muru That sort of seems like both data-recovery and password-recovery. No reason they can't both apply.

Comment: Finally, is the first time I see a post like this in the CB.

Comment: Oh, btw, these post would love also votes, any kind of votes, up, down, close, delete, etc. which is something mentioned [everywhere](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/239191/213575) but somehow everyone forgets.

Comment: @Oli You're a mod. You can do whatever you want, remember?

Comment: @Whaaaaaatare you saying? he is not as powerful as the whole of a bunch of people. Even with his impressive amount of reputation he isn't using askubuntu in god mode, only admin mode. There are some things you just can't do even with everything unlocked, otherwise we'd have one person get 1 million rep somewhere and wreak havoc or turn it into some dictatorship or something.

Comment: @Whaaaaaat this can't be done by automated tools, since the tag is used indistinctly for many things. Manual disambiguation is needed.

Answer (score 1):

Got the linked lists under 20 posts each (and those were about data recovery). Still a few outliers in the main bunch but it was never going to be perfect.

Ding. Dong. The recovery tag is dead.